# How could I make the input box looks like this way based on bootrap

Tags: css

I'm creating my site based on bootstrap But wanna do some customization.

Any idea to overwrite the bootstrap default style with this one

I know to replace the box style to underline only can use this

```
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
```

But not knowing how to bend the line

[image: inline]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up the relevant Bootstrap 3.3.7 (most recent non-alpha) code for you, which would be the `.form-control` class.

If you override that class with the following CSS you will likely achieve the effect you are looking for.

```
.form-control {
  border: 0; /* to hide border initially */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; /* to set the bottom border (the only one we need) */
  border-radius: 8px; /* to round borders or 'bend the line' */
}
```

Thus, `border-radius` is the CSS property you are looking for.